# how to display data in combination of row and column?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi all I have an array I want to display array of data in a table in combination of row and column like below expected output table. All values are getting all values in empty column not under tests.

**output:**

```
 NAME | Test | test2 | test3|
 raj  | pass |       | fail |
 user | fail | pass  |      |
 user1|      |       | pass |
```

below is array of data

```
array(size = 8)
'firstname'       => string 'raj' (length = 20)
'test_title'      => string 'tofel' (length = 5)
'submittimestamp' => string 'pass' (length = 19)
9 =>
array(size = 8)
'firstname'       => string 'user' (length = 5)
'test_title'      => string 'Test 1' (length = 6)
'submittimestamp' => string 'fail' (length = 19)
10 =>
array(size = 8)
'firstname'       => string 'user1' (length = 7)
'test_title'      => string 'test2' (length = 5)
'submittimestamp' => string 'pass' (length = 19)
```

**view:**

below code is to display data in table from array

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Employe Name</th>
        <?php   if(count($recordss))
                               {                               
                     foreach ($recordss as $records) 
                               { 
                                $records = (object)$records;
                                $title=$records->test_title;
                              ?>
        <td>
            <?php  echo ucfirst($title); ?>
        </td>
        <?php  }}?>
    </tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
            <?php 

                  if(count($recordss)){                               
                  foreach ($recordss as $records) { 
                    $records = (object)$records;               
                  ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/employee/<?php echo $records->usr_id;?>"><?php echo ucfirst($records->firstname); ?></td>                                    
           <td><?php echo ucfirst($records->submittimestamp); ?></td> 

    </tr>
   <?php } } ?>

</tbody>                    
</table>
```

I have tried and my output is like below:

```
    NAME |      | Test|test2|test3|
    raj  | pass |     |     |
    user | fail |     |     |
   user1 | fail |     |     |
    raj  | fail |     |     |
    user | pass |     |     |
```

All values are getting in extra column but not under tests. Please help me to solve this thanks. I need to display data like the above output table.

Comment: Fix formatting, and include the 1st foreach in your view.

Comment: i added foreach but still am getting same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added part which extracts the test titles. And fixed the looping to show header titles row first which contain the test titles. Then added succeeding loops to place the results to their corresponding test columns.

You can try the below code.

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
  <?php 
    $recordss = array(
        8 => array(
            'firstname' => 'raj',
            'test_title' => 'tofel',
            'submittimestamp' => 'pass'
        ),
        9 => array(
            'firstname' => 'user',
            'test_title' => 'Test 1',
            'submittimestamp' => 'fail'
        ),
        10 => array(
            'firstname' => 'user1',
            'test_title' => 'test2',
            'submittimestamp' => 'pass'
        ),

        12 => array(
            'firstname' => 'john',
            'test_title' => 'tofel',
            'submittimestamp' => 'fail'
        )
    );  

    if(count($recordss)) {  
        $titles = array_unique(array_column($recordss, 'test_title'));
        array_unshift($titles , 'Name');

        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($titles as $title){
            echo "<th>$title</th>";
        }                       
        echo "</tr>";

        foreach ($recordss as $records) {
            echo "<tr>";
            for($i = 0; $i < count($titles); $i++) {
                if($i == 0){
                    echo "<td>".$records['firstname']."</td>";
                }
                else {
                    if( $records['test_title'] == $titles[$i] )
                        echo "<td>".( $records['submittimestamp'])."</td>";
                    else 
                        echo "<td></td>";
                }
            }
            echo "</tr>";
            ?>
            <?php
        }
    }
  ?>   
</thead>
 </table>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code works by first creating a two dimensional empty grid.  This is done by getting a list of unique courses and employees and making `$grid` have a slot for each employee and each course.  Then it's just a case of going through the original data and putting the mark into each slot.

```
$recordss = array(
    8 => array(
        'firstname' => 'raj',
        'test_title' => 'tofel',
        'submittimestamp' => 'pass'
    ),
    9 => array(
        'firstname' => 'user',
        'test_title' => 'Test 1',
        'submittimestamp' => 'fail'
    ),
    10 => array(
        'firstname' => 'user1',
        'test_title' => 'test2',
        'submittimestamp' => 'pass'
    )
);


$tests = array_unique(array_column($recordss, 'test_title'));
$testDummy = array_fill(0, count($tests), "");
$testBlank = array_combine($tests, $testDummy);
$employees = array_unique(array_column($recordss, 'firstname'));
$grid = array();
foreach ( $employees as $employee ){
    $grid[$employee] = $testBlank;
}

foreach ( $recordss as $record )    {
    $grid[$record['firstname']][$record['test_title']] = $record['submittimestamp'];
}

print_r($grid);
```

With the test data, the output is...

```
Array
(
    [raj] => Array
        (
            [tofel] => pass
            [Test 1] => 
            [test2] => 
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [tofel] => 
            [Test 1] => fail
            [test2] => 
        )

    [user1] => Array
        (
            [tofel] => 
            [Test 1] => 
            [test2] => pass

)

)
```

You just need to wrap this into the format your after by processing each `$grid` row at a time.

**Update:**

View code...

```
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Employe Name</td>
<?php   
    foreach ($tests as $test)   {
            echo "<td>".ucfirst($test)."</td>";
    }?>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($grid as $name => $line) {  ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/employee/<?php echo $name;?>"><?php echo ucfirst($name); ?></td>
        <?php                                    
        foreach ( $line as $testResult )    {
            echo "<td>".ucfirst($testResult)."</td> ";
        } ?>

    </tr>
   <?php } ?>

</tbody>                    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why your output not same as you wish because you do not check the data field, and you print data by vertical not horizontal. Check my code below for detail.

Array data :

```
$recordss = array(
            8 => array(
                'firstname' => 'raj',
                'test_title' => 'tofel',
                'submittimestamp' => 'pass'
            ),
            9 => array(
            'firstname' => 'user',
            'test_title' => 'Test 1',
            'submittimestamp' => 'fail'
            ),
            10 => array(
                'firstname' => 'user1',
                'test_title' => 'test2',
                'submittimestamp' => 'pass'
        ),
        11 => array(
                'firstname' => 'bro',
                'test_title' => 'tofel',
                'submittimestamp' => 'pass'
            ),
            12 => array(
            'firstname' => 'bro',
            'test_title' => 'Test 1',
            'submittimestamp' => 'pass'
        ),
        13 => array(
            'firstname' => 'raj',
            'test_title' => 'Test 1',
            'submittimestamp' => 'pass'
        ),
        14 => array(
            'firstname' => 'user1',
            'test_title' => 'tofel',
            'submittimestamp' => 'pass'
        ),
    );
```

Filter unique name for name columns and filter unique test name for all test name columns.

```
$uniq_rec = array_unique($recordss,SORT_REGULAR);
$uniq_name = array_unique(array_column($recordss, 'firstname'));
$uniq_test = array_unique(array_column($recordss, 'test_title'));
```

Here code view.

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Employe Name</th>
        <?php
        foreach ($uniq_test as $row) {
        ?>
            <th><?php echo $row?></th>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($uniq_name as $row) {
        ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row?>
            <?php
                foreach ($uniq_test as $uniq) {;
                    $status = "";
                    foreach ($recordss as $rec) {
                        if($uniq == $rec['test_title'] && $rec['firstname'] == $row){
                             echo "<td>".$rec['submittimestamp']."</td>";
                            $status = "true";
                        }
                    }
                    if($status != "true"){
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                    $status = "";
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this help you.
Good Luck.